# Access resource files in plugin jars from main application

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I'm developing a main application whose features can be extended via jar files that contain plugins. When my application runs, it simply checks the folder for the plugins, and loads up the classes that it finds there and registers them with my application.

I'd like to develop a help / messages sub-system to my application that uses external resource files (HTML files if possible) to get the help content associated with various parts of the application and to get detailed info/warning/error messages to display to the user.

For all things that pertain to the main application, I can easily determine the relative path to the resource file since I'm keeping those resource files in the same jar as my application class files.

For external plugins, ideally the resource files pertaining to that plugin should live within the jar for that plugin. However, I'm not finding a consistent way to determine the path to those files in the dynamically loaded jars.

Would appreciate any insight into how I could consistently do that for both internal resources and externally provided resources to use the same help / messaging framework provided by the main application.

Answer (score 0):

If  you are trying to load the file from a different plugin, or from the main application code, you'll need an instance of the pluginManager from Spring:

```
InputStream in = pluginManager.getDynamicResourceAsStream(filename)
```

Ref: https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-developer-faq/what-is-the-best-way-to-load-a-class-or-resource-from-a-plugin

Comment: I was trying to get this to work, however it looks like a developer would need the Altassian SDK installed when building / running. That doesn't, unfortunately, fit my scenario